# Why return string format for FINFO function in SAS EG and SAS DI is different

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I am trying to get file "modeified" datetime with

`datetimeString =` finfo(fid,'Last Modified');``

In SAS EG the return string looks like  **12Jan2023:11:03:53**

But in SAS DI the return string looks like **12 January 2023 11:03:28**

I am trying to convert a string to a datetime like below and obviously it doesn't work for EG and throw invalid argument error.
`moddate=input(finfo(fid,'Last Modified'),datetime20.);`

I can fix this by writing bit of extra code in DI but would like to know why `finfo(fid,'Last Modified');` return different string format?

I am working in data step.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same SAS server with both of those front end applications?

Comment: @tom, yes connecting to  same SAS server and same files. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the setting of the LOCALE option in the two different SAS sessions.

You can use the NLDATM informat to read the string generated by FINFO()

[SAS Documentation on NLDATM informat](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/nlsref/n1q5hrj5lwe5e1n1xymum8nvqznl.htm)

[Example program that uses NLDATM informat to get datetime from FINFO() function.](https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/dirtree.sas)

Comment: thanks @tom for pointing in the right direction, i checked the locale settings for DI and EG and found they were local for EG but server based for DI.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different in-format

```
37         data _null_;
38            x = '12 January 2023 11:03:28';
39            moddate=input(x,datetime20.);
40            moddate2=input(x,anydtdtm30.);
41            put 'NOTE: ' (mod:)(=datetime.);
42            run;

NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 39 column 12.
NOTE: moddate=. moddate2=12JAN23:11:03:28
```

Comment: that's a better option  to fix the issue. thank you. but i was interested in knowing why the string return from DI and EG is different, is there any locale setting causing it ?